# How can I test credentials with javascript

Tags: javascript, credentials, here-api

How can I test user credentials using javascript?

I tested the good URL with `app_code` and `app_id`. When they are ok all other requests seem to be ok too.

Comment: If you are trying to authenticate(I suppose you are) using javascript, it's a very bad idea. Should be handled in server side code. Having said that I don't have much idea about here-api

Comment: Welcome to SO. Where is the code problem in this question?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it so e.g.:

```
var app_id = "test_app_id";
var app_code = "test_app_code";
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4 ) {
    if(this.responseText.indexOf("France") != -1){
      console.log("Credentials is OK");
    }else{console.log("Wrong credentials");} 
  }
});

xhr.open("GET", "https://geocoder.api.here.com/6.2/geocode.json?app_id="+ app_id+"&app_code=" + app_code + "&country=FRA");
xhr.send();
```